# Styles.css not getting applied in Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

The problem that I have is that I have some code that defines a website and that defines its constituent stylesheet. I have linked the stylesheet and have a function for wordpress written, to enqueue the stylesheet, however it doesn't seem to want to load. When I try to apply the style without a

```
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

it does not apply any style, wheras, if I do include it, developer tools display an error:

```
"Error : Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/javascript:"
```

The main.php page in question:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>main</title>

<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


<style type="text/css">
.header
{
background : #FFFFFF;
background : rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
width : 100%;
height : 98pt;
}

.image
{
background-image : url(image.png);
position : relative ;
left : 52pt;
top : 133pt;
width : 19pt;
height : 20pt;
}


images {
width: 70%;
}
</style>

</head>
...
```

Then the functions file:

```
<?php

function SetStyles() {

wp_enqueue_style('style',  get_stylesheet_uri() );

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'SetStyles');
```

And finally, the start of styles.css:

```
@charset "utf-8";
.images {
width: 59%;
display: block;
float: right;
font-size: 59.87pt;
font-family: "Mrs Eaves OT", "Mrs Eaves Small Caps OT";
font-variant: small-caps;
}

}
.links {
clear: right;
vertical-align: baseline;
width: 72%;
height: 25px;
float: right;
font-family: "Futura PT Light";
font-size: 25px;
word-spacing: 30px;
...
```

Would really appreciate someone helping me out, its been driving me mad. 
Edit: I should also add that the styles do appear to be correctly displayed in my DreamWeaver editor, only is it in browser that they dissapear.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `wp_enqueue_scripts` instead of [`wp_enqueue_style`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/). Thus, WordPress wraps your resource into `javascript` mime type.

Pay attention to your error messages. Question everything.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Though it doesn't seem to be the issue, as I tried changing it to no avail. It looks like the error is present at 

    `<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

Answer (score 0):

What the name of your stylesheet **style.css or styles.css** ?? If it is **styles.css** change the below line in your code

```
wp_enqueue_style('styles',  get_stylesheet_uri() );
```

This will look for a stylesheet named “**styles**” and load it, also make sure your stylesheet is in your theme’s root directory.

Hope this helps.